# How to find FIRST and FOLLOW

Tags: compiler-construction, context-free-grammar

I want to find FIRST and FOLLOW for the following CFG:

```
S -> O | M
M -> iEtMeM | a
O -> iEtS | iEtMeO
E -> b
```

I did the left factorization, so I get:

```
S -> O | M
M -> iEtMeM | a
O -> iEtO'
O'-> S | MeO
E -> b
```

The FIRST sets:

```
FIRST(S) = FIRST(O)|FIRST(M) = {i,a}
FIRST(M) = {i,a}
FIRST(O) = {i}
FIRST(O') = FIRST(S)|FIRST(M) = {i,a}
FIRST(E) = {b}
```

And now I cant find the FOLLOW set for `S` , because I don't know what `FOLLOW(O')` is:

```
FOLLOW(S) = {$, FOLLOW(O')}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Actually `FOLLOW(S) = {$}` only.</s>

So, I overlooked that `S` is mentioned on a right-hand
side. Corrections below:

First we get the augmented grammar by adding the production `S' ->S$`, then
`FOLLOW(S') = {$}`.

Then we have

- from `S' -> S$` and `O' -> S`

  FOLLOW(S) = FIRST($) + FOLLOW(O')
- from `M -> iEtMeM`, `O' -> MeO`, and `S -> M`

  FOLLOW(M) = FIRST(eM) + FIRST(eO) + FOLLOW(S)
- from `S -> O` and  `O' -> MeO`

  FOLLOW(O) = FOLLOW(S) + FOLLOW(O')
- from `O -> iEtO'`

  FOLLOW(O') = FOLLOW(O)
- from `M -> iEtMeM` and `O -> iEtO'`

  FOLLOW(E) = FIRST(tMeM) + FIRST(tO')

The "problem" are the mutually recursive definitions for
`FOLLOW(S)`, `FOLLOW(O)`, and `FOLLOW(O') - that means that each
of these follow sets is a subset of the others, hence they are
equal.

If one represent the set inclusion constraints, imposed by the
above equations, as a graph (with non-terminal symbols as nodes),
each set of mutually recursive definitions forms a
strongly-connected component. Replacing each SCC with a new
node will result in a DAG, representing a set of
non-recursive equations, which can then by "evaluated" in
topological order.

Say, we replace nodes, corresponding to symbols `S`, `O` and `O'` with node `N`. The equations become:

```
FOLLOW(N) = FIRST($) + FOLLOW(N)
FOLLOW(M) = FIRST(eM) + FIRST(eO) + FOLLOW(N)
FOLLOW(N) = FOLLOW(N) + FOLLOW(N)
FOLLOW(N) = FOLLOW(N)
FOLLOW(E) = FIRST(tMeM) + FIRST(tO')
```

and by cutting off the redundant parts:

```
FOLLOW(N) = FIRST($) = {$}
FOLLOW(M) = FIRST(eM) + FIRST(eO) + FOLLOW(N) = {e, $}
FOLLOW(E) = FIRST(tMeM) + FIRST(tO') = {t}
```

and, since `N` stands for either `S`, `O`, or `O'` we get:

```
FOLLOW(S`) = FOLLOW(S) = FOLLOW(O) = FOLLOW(O`) = {$}
FOLLOW(M) = {e, $}
FOLLOW(E) = {t}
```

Comment: Hi chill, but why is `FOLLOW(S)` only `{$}` it is present also here `O'-> S | MeO`

Comment: @Gabriel, yeah, I overlooked that mention of `S`, see edited answer.